# VRAM vs GTT memory usage

Tags: opengl, memory-management, driver

I have an OpenGL application (on Linux) which, at each frame, displays 1000 buffers of 4 Mo each. If I track the memory usage under radeontop, the VRAM roughly increases by 50-100 Mo and the GTT by 4 Go (on a total of respectively 8127M and 8166M). Why the VRAM usage is so low, knowing that 90% of it is left unusued?

Comment: What is a "Mo"? Or a "Go" for that matter?

Comment: @httpdigest Your first guess is right, that is exactly my question. I’m not saying that my application would be faster if all the buffers were located in VRAM, I’m just curious to know why.

Comment: They are partially updated at each frame when I move the camera, but they are left untouched otherwise. I’ve made my test without moving around.

Answer (score 2):

Hinting OpenGL to create my buffers for GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW (instead of GL_STREAM_DRAW) happens to fix this befavior. I’ve overloked this setting since it is not exactly how I use them, but in the end, it is faster.